# Error in this python code

Tags: python

```
while True:
print ("Options")
print ("Write 'Quit' if you want to exit")
print ("Write '+'if you want to make an addition")
print ("Write '-' if you want to make a sottration")
print ("Write '*' if you want to make a moltiplication")
print ("Write '/' if you wantto make a division")
user_input == input(":")
         if user_input == ("+")
         num1 = float(input("Enter a number...")
         num2 = float(input("Enter the second number...")
         result = str(num1+num2)
         print("The result is"+ result)
         elif user_input == ("-")
         num1 = float(input("Enter a number...")  
         num2 = float(input("Enter the second number...")
         result = str(num1-num2)
         print("The result is"+ result)
         elif user_input == ("*")
         num1 = float(input("Enter a number...")
         num2 = float(input("Enter the second number...")
         result = str(num1*num2)
         print("The result is"+ result)
         elif user_input == ("/")
         num1 = float(input("Enter a number...")
         num2 = float(input("Enter the second number...")
         print ("The result is"+ result)
```

This is the code I have created in python 2.7, but it does not work. I think there's an indentation error. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, it's an `IndentationError` (but also a `SyntaxError` because you forgot the `:` after the `if` conditions). Is the code you have exactly indented like shown in the question?

Comment: What makes you think there an indentation error that makes it "not function"? What have you done to try to fix it?

Comment: Consider watching an introductory Python tutorial. It will certainly help.

Comment: sorry for my errors,i'm an italian student,and i'm learning this programming language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your indentation and add a colon after each `if-statement` as the following and change `user_input == input(':')` to `user_input = input(':')`:

```
while True:
    print ("Options")
    print ("Write 'Quit' if you want to exit")
    print ("Write '+'if you want to make an addition")
    print ("Write '-' if you want to make a sottration")
    print ("Write '*' if you want to make a moltiplication")
    print ("Write '/' if you wantto make a division")
    user_input = input(":") # fix this line
    if user_input == ("+"):
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number..."))
        num2 = float(input("Enter the second number..."))
        result = str(num1+num2)
        print("The result is"+ result)
    elif user_input == ("-"):
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number..."))  
        num2 = float(input("Enter the second number..."))
        result = str(num1-num2)
        print("The result is"+ result)
    elif user_input == ("*"):
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number..."))
        num2 = float(input("Enter the second number..."))
        result = str(num1*num2)
        print("The result is"+ result)
    elif user_input == ("/"):
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number..."))
        num2 = float(input("Enter the second number..."))
        result = str(num1/num2)
        print ("The result is"+ result)
```

**EDIT:**

Below is a better version of your code that fixes few errors, like reading string input, avoid dividing by zero exception and removing `float()` type casting because in python 2.7 `input()` already does that for you.

```
while True:
    print("Options")
    print("Write 'Quit' if you want to exit")
    print("Write '+'if you want to make an addition")
    print("Write '-' if you want to make a sottration")
    print("Write '*' if you want to make a moltiplication")
    print("Write '/' if you wantto make a division")
    user_input = raw_input(":")
    if user_input == '+':
        num1 = input("Enter a number...")
        num2 = input("Enter the second number...")
        print('The result is {}'.format(num1+num2))
    elif user_input == '-':
        num1 = input("Enter a number...")
        num2 = input("Enter the second number...")
        print('The result is {}'.format(num1-num2))
    elif user_input == '*':
        num1 = input("Enter a number...")
        num2 = input("Enter the second number...")
        print('The result is {}'.format(num1*num2))
    elif user_input == '/':
        num1 = input("Enter a number...")
        num2 = input("Enter the second number...")
        if num2 == 0:
            print("Can't divide by zero.")
        else:
            print("The result is {}".format(num1/num2))
```

Also as suggested by other users here is an improved version:

```
while True:
    print("Options")
    print("Write 'Quit' if you want to exit")
    print("Write '+'if you want to make an addition")
    print("Write '-' if you want to make a sottration")
    print("Write '*' if you want to make a moltiplication")
    print("Write '/' if you wantto make a division")
    user_input = raw_input(":") 
    num1 = input("Enter a number...")
    num2 = input("Enter the second number...")

    if user_input == "+":
        result = str(num1+num2)
    elif user_input == "-":
        result = str(num1-num2)
    elif user_input == "*":
        result = str(num1*num2)
    elif user_input == "/":
        if num2 == 0:
            result = "Can't divide by zero"
        else:
            result = str(num1/num2)

    print("The result is", result)
```

Comment: And why not putting the duplicated "Enter a number..."s outside the elif? Would save 6 lines! If you do it, I upvote :D

Comment: I guess you need to also use `raw_input`. The question stated that python-2.7 is used.

Comment: I will just re-write it instead of that edited version of the OP's code

Comment: i resolved,thanks a lot:-)

Comment: sorry for my errors,i'm an italian student,and i'm learning this programming language...

Comment: @SergioPrinci Glad to help, good luck with your studies :)